# DB2 v10 zos : identify free index values

Tags: sql, db2, zos

My organisation has hundreds of DB2 tables that each have a randomly generated unique integer index. The random values are generated by either COBOL CICS mainframe programs or Java distributed applications. The normal approach taken is to randomly generate an integer value (only positive values are employed), then attempt to insert the data row, retrying when a duplicate index value has already been persisted. I would like to improve the performance of this approach and I'm considering trying to identify integer values that have not been generated and persisted to each table, this would mean we don't ever need to retry. We would know our insert would work. Does db2 have a function that can return unused index values?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you should look into using [`sequences`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_sequences.dita).

Comment: bhamby, thanks for looking at this, however sequences are not an acceptable solution. it has to be random and sequences are incremental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The slightly longer answer is to point out that, if such a function existed, in your case on the first insert into one of your tables the size of the result set it would return would be 2,147,483,647 (positive) integers.  At 4 bytes each, that would be 8,589,934,588 bytes.

Given the constraints of your existing system, what you're doing is probably the best that can be done.  If the performance of retrying is unacceptable, I'm afraid redesigning your key scheme is the next step.

I think that's a question to ask: Is this scheme of using random numbers for unique keys causing a performance problem?  As the tables fill up the key space you will see more and more retries, but you have a relatively large key space.  If you're seeing large numbers of retries maybe your random numbers are less random than you'd like.

Comment: cschneid, thanks for looking at my issue; My solution was this; i). generate lower limit as random positive integer. ii). calculate upper limit by adding constant X (e.g. 50) to my random lower limit. iii). populate a java ArrayList<Integer> with all number between my LOWER & UPPER limit. iv). retrieve a ArrayList<Integer> of all used integer values from a DB2 table. v). remove all values returned in previous step from ArrayList generated in step iii .vi). i now have an ArrayList<Integer> that contains all available index values for the current table.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought but you could use one sequence for a group of tables. In this way, the value will still be random (because you wouldn't know which it the next table you perform an insert to) but based on a specific sequance wich mean that most of the time you won't get a retry because the number keep ascending. that same Sequance can loop after a few hunderd million inserts and start to "fill in the blanks".

as far as other key ideas are concerned,You could also try and use a diffrent key, maybe one based on Timestamp or Rowid. that will still be random but not repetitive.